# SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream streaming realtime audio

Tags: c#, .net-3.5

In .NET 3.5, System.Speech.Recognition SpeechRecognitionEngine.SetInputToAudioStream Method doesn't seem to support real-time input.

I am developing a windows application and I want to provide real-time input stream over the network. How could I accomplish this? Could someone help me with a work-around?

Thank you.

Comment: how do you know it doesn't support realtime input?  what happens?

Comment: I have read it on MSDN community content http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognitionengine.setinputtoaudiostream(v=VS.90).aspx

Comment: Important thing to know here is that you define what kind of stream do you want to feed?

Answer (score 1):

Can you do something where you buffer 5 second samples and send that in as a stream rather than the live stream direct from the network?  The problem with that approach is you could break mid word, and I'm not sure how that is dealt with programmatically.

According to that community post, if the internal wrapper doesn't support the required interface, there isn't much you can do except keep feeding it samples.  You could write your own custom input stream as well.  What happens when you just feed the engine the network stream directly?